# Printing out the Order + Total Cost

Tags: python

So, I'm still fairly new to Python, but I'm having significant trouble due to it no longer printing out what the total is as the code moves along. So after asking for the sandwich, and entering one of the three selections, it goes straight to the next question. I don't understand why it does this... but the beginning of my code is looking like this.

```
order = ("**** YOUR ORDER INCLUDES \n ")
totalCost = 0.00
comboStatus = 0
```

This is essentially what it looks like in each section for the sandwiches, drinks, and fries.

```
while true:
    sandChoice = input("Select your sandwich! Please enter 1, 2, or 3.")
    if sandChoice not in ('1', '2', '3'):
       print("Your response is invalid. Try again.")
    else:
        sandChoice = str(sandChoice)
        break

if (sandChoice == 1):
    print("You chose Chicken!")
    totalCost += 5.25
    print("Your total is now $" + str(totalCost))
    order += ("CHICKEN SANDWICH  \n")
    comboStatus += 1

if (sandChoice == 2):
    print("You chose Tofu!")
    totalCost += 5.75
    print("Your total is now $" + str(totalCost))
    order += ("TOFU SANDWICH \n")
    comboStatus += 1 

if (sandChoice == 3):
    print("You chose Steak!")
    totalCost += 6.25
    print("Your total is now $" + str(totalCost,2))
    order += ("STEAK SANDWICH \n")
    comboStatus += 1
```

However at the end, this is what my code looks like

```
print('The total cost of your order is $' + str(totalCost) + '. \n')
```

If anyone could give me any tips in order to improve the function and make the code work, It would definitely help.

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: Also `sandChoice ` is a string, then you compare it to ints, do `sandChoice = int(sandChoice)`

Comment: since you are just comparing for values, you can do `sandChoice == '1'` and you dont need to convert it to `int()`

Comment: @azro I'm still having trouble understanding the site's way to indent as I used to just look at already answered questions but then figured the best way to learn would be to finally begin to post my own. My first question was when I figured out how to add code into my questions, I do appreciate it though. I will definitely try and utilize the indent system more. Is there a way to automatically indent my code when I enter it though?

Comment: Your code should be indented where you have it on your laptop, so when you copy/paste it there, it keep the indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of get the general picture of the program that you want. I modified your code a bit

Updated code here

```
order = ("**** YOUR ORDER INCLUDES \n ")
totalCost = 0.00
comboStatus = 0

while True:
    print("Select your sandwich!")
    print("[1] Chicken sandwich - $5.25")
    print("[2] Tofu - $5.75")
    print("[3] Steak - $6.25")
    print("[4] Exit")
    sandChoice = input("Enter choice: ")

    if sandChoice not in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
       print("Your response is invalid. Try again.")
       continue

    sandChoice = int(sandChoice)

    if (sandChoice == 1):
        print("You chose Chicken!")
        totalCost += 5.25
        print("Your total is now $", totalCost)
        order += ("CHICKEN SANDWICH  \n")
        comboStatus += 1
    elif (sandChoice == 2):
        print("You chose Tofu!")
        totalCost += 5.75
        print("Your total is now $", totalCost)
        order += ("TOFU SANDWICH \n")
        comboStatus += 1
    elif (sandChoice == 3):
        print("You chose Steak!")
        totalCost += 6.25
        print("Your total is now $", totalCost)
        order += ("STEAK SANDWICH \n")
        comboStatus += 1
    elif (sandChoice == 4):
        break

print('The total cost of your order is $' + str(totalCost) + '. \n')
```

Comment: So I noticed that after I did this section to try and fix it when I started running the program, it won't move onto the next part where it asks for a drink. Any ideas why it is doing that?

Comment: Here is my running code.                                                                                                           Welcome to the Sandwich Shop. We offer Sandwiches, Drinks, and Fries.
Select your sandwich!
[1] Chicken sandwich - $5.25
[2] Tofu - $5.75
[3] Steak - $6.25
[4] Exit
Enter choice: 3
You chose Steak!
Your total is now $ 6.25
Select your sandwich!
[1] Chicken sandwich - $5.25
[2] Tofu - $5.75
[3] Steak - $6.25
[4] Exit
Enter choice:

Comment: It keeps repeating and I don't understand why? If you could explain why it does this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Dippy_Scff Do you mean to ask why it keeps on repeating even after you enter your choice?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I meant to say it like that. It's just I'm in a rush to get this done for tomorrow.

Comment: @Dippy_Scff I'm willing to help, where is the link?

Comment: Just so you know, at the end it has to print out all the selections you made as a final order, and the ketchup packets have to be entered like if you want 25 packets, it will take in the value. It is supposed to be 25 cents a packet.

Comment: @Dippy_Scff Done! Can you mark my answer correct if it helped you? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Alrighty! Thanks! It´s done so I appreciate it. I will definitely try to understand everything added so I can code in python more to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there are some other questions in your code, following the same format of the very one you posted, and your script seems not to outputting the answer provided in the if statements.

The reason for which it is happening is that you have specified, in case of valid answer, that `sandChoice = str(sandChoice)`, thus converting that to a **string**. In your if statements, however, you are comparing sandChoice to an **integer**.

Remember that `'1'` is not equal to `1`.

To solve it, either set `sandChoice = int(sandChoice)` or compare to a string in your if statements, like: `if (sandChoice == '1'):`

Find below a working version of the total code you posted

```
order = ("**** YOUR ORDER INCLUDES \n ")
totalCost = 0.00
comboStatus = 0

while True:
    sandChoice = input("Select your sandwich! Please enter 1, 2, or 3.")
    if sandChoice not in ('1', '2', '3'):
       print("Your response is invalid. Try again.")
    else:
        sandChoice = int(sandChoice)
        break

if (sandChoice == 1):
    print("You chose Chicken!")
    totalCost += 5.25
    print("Your total is now $" + str(totalCost))
    order += ("CHICKEN SANDWICH  \n")
    comboStatus += 1
if (sandChoice == 2):
    print("You chose Tofu!")
    totalCost += 5.75
    print("Your total is now $" + str(totalCost))
    order += ("TOFU SANDWICH \n")
    comboStatus += 1 
if (sandChoice == 3):
    print("You chose Steak!")
    totalCost += 6.25
    print("Your total is now $" + str(totalCost,2))
    order += ("STEAK SANDWICH \n")
    comboStatus += 1

print('The total cost of your order is $' + str(totalCost) + '. \n')
```

Comment: I was looking at the code and began using it, when I went to start using it in other sections, the error remained occuring.

Comment: Which other sections, though? Is it working correctly for the section you posted? I am afraid I won't be able to help diagnosing what's the problem on the "other sections" if you don't show the relevant code

Comment: I understand you are in a rush to get this done by tomorrow, my piece of advice for you is to try to slow down a bit, as that will help you avoiding mistakes and learn better and faster. I understand in some sections you ask for a drink as well. Are you sure that the comparison, in those sections, is properly occuring? i.e. in your if statements you are not comparing string and integers, like before?

Comment: I have it going from str to str, I took out the int in all other sections as well, and making it be str only. This is occurring throughout the entire program. Ill edit the code above so you can see the other sections as well.